# Rewrite as one mySQL query where results of 1st query needed for 2nd query

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL query similar to this:

```
SELECT c1, c2 FROM a WHERE a.c3 = 123
```

I have a second query that I need to execute for each value of c2 like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Counter` FROM a WHERE a.c2 = [each value of a.c2]
```

At the moment, I programmatically loop through each result from the first query and perform the second query.  So, what's happening is that the main query uses a specific value of c3 to generate a result set.  Then, the second query uses that result set and does the COUNT for each returned value of c2 without any limitation on values for c3.

Is it possible to rewrite the first query so that it also returns the aggregate results for `Counter`?  In other words, I want to end up with a result set which includes `c1, c2, Counter`.

I tried writing a subquery, but this doesn't work:

```
SELECT c1, c2,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Counter` FROM a)
FROM a WHERE a.c3 = 123
```

(I don't know how to make the WHERE clause use the retrieved values from the "main" query.)

I'm working with an older application which is using mySQL 4.1.

EDIT to show data and desired result:

Assume that table `a` looks as follows:

```
| c1  |  c2 |
|+++++++++++|
| 222 | 101 |
| 223 | 101 |
| 224 | 101 |
| 222 | 102 |
| 223 | 102 |
```

Given a specified value for c2, I find all the matching values of c1.  So, if `c2=101`:

```
| c1  |
|+++++|
| 222 |
| 223 |
| 224 |
```

Now, for each of these 3 values, I want to `Count` the number of times the value appears in the full table `a`:

```
| c1  | count |
|+++++++++++++|
| 222 | 2     |
| 223 | 2     |
| 224 | 1     |
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are looking for results... Can you show some sample data that show the repeated rows / values, and what you EXPECT based on the sample data as a return set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still holding... try this...  The inner query gets distinct "c1" values for the one ID you are looking for (ie:101).  That is a distinct list to now re-join to the original FULL table, but only on those "c1" values found.  Then group by all that are found and order based on the DESCENDING count to put the highest to the top of the list.

```
SELECT 
      a.c1,
      COUNT(*) as NumCount
   from 
      ( select distinct a.c1
           from a where a.c2 = 101 ) GetThese
         JOIN a
            ON GetThese.c1 = a.c1
   group by
      a.c1
   order by 
      COUNT(*) DESC,
      a.c1
```

Comment: Our solutions look very similar.  Is there a difference in efficiency?

Comment: @jalperin, they are virtually identical, only significant difference is the order by applied after looking closer.  But since there was no answer as "checked" indicating a solution WAS found, I didn't even look at the other answer as I was away for more time from original comment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with a simple join:

```
SELECT a.c1, a.c2, count(*) as `counter` FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.c2 = b.c2
WHERE a.c3 = 123
GROUP BY a.c1, a.c2
```

Comment: yes, you're correct, but I made a mistake in my question by oversimplifying the problem.  Actually, table b is the same table as a.  Once I've performed the main query which includes a WHERE clause for c3 limiting it to a single value, I need to re-query the same table for each value of c2 without narrowing the result based on c3.

Comment: Okay, so in that instance simply take out the entire line starting left join. Your question still references a second table, b, in places. If you can update the question I will update the answer fully.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a join to a temporary table created with a subquery.

```
SELECT b.c1 , COUNT(*)
FROM a
JOIN  (SELECT c1
FROM a
WHERE c2=XXXX) 
AS `b`
ON a.c1 = b.c1  
GROUP BY b.c1
```

Comment: Note that this is pretty similar to @DRapp's solution above

Answer (score 0):

Just join the table against itself and use count:-

```
SELECT a.c1, a.c2, COUNT(b.c1)
FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN a b
ON a.c1 = b.c1
WHERE a.c2 = 101
GROUP BY a.c1
```